# Chrome Extension Context Menu creates several Subitems & Only works when Popup is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to implement a context menu in my chrome extension, so that you can select a text and right-click to process it further.

The menu is there and it partly works, however I have two issues:
[image]

For some reason, it creates subitems every time you right-click some text, it varies between 2 and 5. My guess it that it has to do with the extension not properly updating the context menu.

The second issue is that the processing (so the function below which gets executed onclick) only works when the popup is open, otherwise it does not call the function. My guess here is that something needs to be done in the background, currently all the functions are located in popup.js.

```
function contextMenuClick(selectionText) {

   chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
   var selection = selectionText;
   console.log(selectionText);
   //further processing
})
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Push: %s", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  onclick: function(info, tab) { 
    contextMenuClick(info.selectionText);
  }
});
```

Question: How do I make sure it does not create those subitems, what is the cause of this? Why does it only works while the popup is open? How can I enable background capabilities for this?

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)  (and perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you have the code you show in the question in your *popup.js* instead of a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages). This is code that belongs in your background script.

> How can I enable background capabilities for this?

You define a background script by adding the `background` key to your *manifest.json*.  For a script file called *background.js*:

```json
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},
```

> How do I make sure it does not create those subitems, what is the cause of this?

You are creating a new context menu item every time you execute `chrome.contextMenus.create()`. If you create multiple entries, they are automatically placed within a pull-right menu with the name of your extension. Given that this code is in your *popup.js*, it is likely that you are creating a new entry every time your popup is opened. You have not provided enough code for us to know that this is actually what is happening, but it is likely.

You make sure the pull-right menu and sub-items are not created by only creating a single context menu item. One of the easiest ways to do this is to have your call to `chrome.contextMenus.create()` in your background script where it will be executed once, instead of every time your popup is opened.

> Why does it only works while the popup is open?

The popup is like a web page. If it is not being shown, it does not exist. Thus, the function, `contextMenuClick` which you are calling from within the context menu `onclick` event listener does not exist unless the popup is open. If it does not exist, it can not be called.